# how to find matched text using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I extract the word following "text:" using a regular expression? The input is something like:

```
some string some string (text:the_word_i_want_to_get some string) some string
some string some string (text:next_word_i_want_to_get some string) some string
```

and the output should be:

```
["the_word_i_want_to_get", "next_word_i_want_to_get"]
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit better?

Comment: @David: I tried rewriting your question more clearly; does the new version still say what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the *first* occurrence of your word like this:

```
var input = "some string...",// Assume this is what you wrote in your question.
    match = input.match(/text:(\w+)/)[1];
```

To get all of the matches, you could put it in a loop:

```
while (/text:(\w+)/) {
  matches.push(input.match(/text:(\w+)/)[1]);
  input = input.replace(/text:(\w+)/, "");
}
```